# how to extract installables from installed nodejs module?

Tags: node.js, extract, node-modules

I am able to figure out where a nodejs module is installed using this command (as suggested at this [reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077866/how-to-extract-installables-from-installed-nodejs-module))

```
npm list -g
```

But how can I extract a module from this location so that I can install the same on a different system?

Comment: what you mean by extract here?

Comment: @RajaSekar I want to know if I can extract installables from the installed folder of a nodejs module.

Comment: I think it is not possible, u mean u wanna copy those files and have to use in another machine

Comment: @RajaSekar yes that is what I meant. Let me know if it is possible

Comment: if you need specific module to be copied, use 'which packagename' for example 'which bower' will give the exact location where it is installed. u can copy and use it in other machine. Just curious to know what is the use case?

Comment: @RajaSekar command `which packagename` doesn't work. I get `ReferenceError: which is not defined`

Comment: Or do `npm i someModule` inside an empty folder, you'll have the package's entire folder. Also, if you're on Windows, you can use `where packageName`.

Comment: You really shouldn't just copy a module from one system another as you don't know you'll get all the things you need to run it elsewhere. It might, for instance, require compilation of a native extension that might not be compatible with your target. This is why `npm install MODULENAME` is so handy. Just run that command on your target and you'll be sure to get everything you need.

Comment: And for the record, the UNIX (Linux, OSX)  `which` command only finds executable programs in your PATH (or shell aliases), not Node modules.